# Fetching List of SilverStripe BlogPosts in RelatedPosts DataObject filter by Categories

Tags: blogs, silverstripe

I am extending silverstripe blog module. Currenly I have developed the RelatedTopic DataObject. This will have a list of existing blog posts to be selected as Relatedtopic.

In my RelatedTopic DataObject:

```
    public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $CategoryLink = new DropdownField('BlogPostIDByCategory', 'Blog List', **Here need to pull the list of all the blogposts which are under the same category as the parent blogpost is**);
```

So basically, I want all blogs in this dropdown field that have the same categories as this current blogpost has.

Remember i m creating Relatedtopic for a blogpost it self. In my blogpostextension i have defined relatedtopics as

```
private static $many_many = array(
    'RelatedTopics' => 'RelatedTopic',
);    

public static $many_many_extraFields = array(
    'RelatedTopics' => array(
    )
);
```

Any help on this will be highly appriciated.

Comment: Since one Blog-Post can have many related-topics, a related-topic DataObject will potentially have multiple blogposts assigned… so there's no "current" or "parent" blog-post but multiple thereof. Maybe you should explain more clearly what your intention is.

Comment: So, you want to get all categories from the BlogPosts related to a RelatedTopic and restrict the selection to BlogPosts that have these categories? All categories, or just one of them?

Comment: Yes, you are right. In my case this is what i am doing. Under the blog holder page. I have a tab for the list of all the blog posts. When you click on any blog from the list it will have its edit screen opened. At that point their is another tab (related articles) next to this blogpost. From this related article tab you can create related topic data object

Comment: So in this case when you are creating a new related topic technically it is under that particular blogpost. On the related article "add related topic" button I want to show the drop down list of articles that are under the same category as that main blogpost. Hope I am clear on this. Thanks

Comment: Yes I want to load the blog posts that are under the categories of parent blogpost. For e.g parent article has 3 categories linked to it say Money, Finance and News. So the drop down should show all the articles that are linked to News, finance and Money. Thansk